# python executable keeps crashing

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a small python script that prints my total memory on my computer:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
import psutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('test')
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    result = mem.total
    print(result)
```

When I execute it by using:

```
sebastien@sebastien-PC:~/Documents$ python3 python-tests/metrictest.py
```

I get the right output. Now I changed it to an executable file and it keeps crashing.

```
sebastien@sebastien-PC:~/Documents$ ls -al python-tests/metrictest.py 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sebastien sebastien 161 Jun  9 12:27 python-tests/metrictest.py
```

It is doing nothing untill I start clicking elsewhere and my cursor becomes a double cross and then I get the following error.

```
sebastien@sebastien-PC:~/Documents$ python-tests/metrictest.py 
python-tests/metrictest.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `'test''
python-tests/metrictest.py: line 6: `    print('test')'
```

How can I fix this that I just get the result that I need?

Comment: What happens when you run command `/usr/bin/env python3` from command line? Which version of python is spawned?

Comment: then python 3.5.2 opens exactly the same way as if would just launch it by typing `python3`

Comment: How did you turn it into a executable ?

Comment: I changed it by using chmod in my cli `chmod 755 -R python-tests/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `#` and `!` in your first line.